# Building an IOS app using corona sdk (certificate not installed)

Tags: certificate, coronasdk, provisioning-profile

I am creating an app using corona sdk for IOS. When I tried to build this app on device, in code signing identity dropdown menu it shows me provisioning profiles but not let me select them as it says certificate is not installed.
I followed the steps and download the certificate in keychain Access and place the profile properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try with genious version... Downliad from officials site and try again...  working fine with mw...

Answer (score 0):

I also found this issue in my app..Please check -
   1- Valid Provisioning Profile and its valid certificate
   2- Close your project from IDE and reopen Corona IDE i.e. LuaGlider etc.
   3- Run your app - Select File - Build - iOS
   4- again add Code signing Identity.

These steps solved my problem.

Comment: my problem is solved as I am an apple developer as a team member and my admin had not checked my certificate.
But now the issue is everything is fine but when I tried to install application in IOS device using iphone configuration utility, it says 
**the application has not valid signature**
can you give me any hint why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through -

**http://jp.anscamobile.com/dev/content/building-devices-iphoneipad/index.html**

This will help you for all your problems.